# Routing Error in rails app 'uninitialized constant HomeController'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, zurb-foundation, rails-routing

Im new to use foundation and i have created simple Posts app using scaffold
and i have done following steps:

```
rails new blog
```

then added following to Gemfile

```
gem 'foundation-rails'
group :development do
  gem 'rails_layout'
end
```

and then

```
$ bundle install
$ rails generate layout:install foundation5 --force
$ rails g scaffold Post title desc:text
$ rake db:migrate
```

Now app runs fine @ local host port 3000/posts
[image]
But when i click on 'Home' button in nav-bar it generates errors:
[image]

application.html.erb file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title><%= content_for?(:title) ? yield(:title) : "Found Rails" %></title>
    <meta name="description" content="<%= content_for?(:description) ? yield(:description) : "Found Rails" %>">
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    <%# Modernizr is required for Zurb Foundation %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'vendor/modernizr' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <%= render 'layouts/navigation' %>
    </header>
    <main role="main">
       <%= render 'layouts/messages' %>
       <%= yield %>
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

_navigation.html.erb file :

```
<%# navigation styled for Zurb Foundation 5 %>
<nav class="top-bar" data-topbar>
  <ul class="title-area">
    <li class="name"><%= link_to 'Home', root_path %></li>
    <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="top-bar-section">
    <ul>
      <%= render 'layouts/navigation_links' %>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

My routes.rb file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :posts
  root :to => "home#index"

  # The priority is based upon order of creation: first created -> highest priority.
  # See how all your routes lay out with "rake routes".

  # You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
  # root 'welcome#index'

  # Example of regular route:
  #   get 'products/:id' => 'catalog#view'

  # Example of named route that can be invoked with purchase_url(id: product.id)
  #   get 'products/:id/purchase' => 'catalog#purchase', as: :purchase

  # Example resource route (maps HTTP verbs to controller actions automatically):
  #   resources :products

  # Example resource route with options:
  #   resources :products do
  #     member do
  #       get 'short'
  #       post 'toggle'
  #     end
  #
  #     collection do
  #       get 'sold'
  #     end
  #   end

  # Example resource route with sub-resources:
  #   resources :products do
  #     resources :comments, :sales
  #     resource :seller
  #   end

  # Example resource route with more complex sub-resources:
  #   resources :products do
  #     resources :comments
  #     resources :sales do
  #       get 'recent', on: :collection
  #     end
  #   end

  # Example resource route with concerns:
  #   concern :toggleable do
  #     post 'toggle'
  #   end
  #   resources :posts, concerns: :toggleable
  #   resources :photos, concerns: :toggleable

  # Example resource route within a namespace:
  #   namespace :admin do
  #     # Directs /admin/products/* to Admin::ProductsController
  #     # (app/controllers/admin/products_controller.rb)
  #     resources :products
  #   end
end
```

What is it that im missing?.

Comment: Do you have a HomeController?

Comment: @iceman no what should be defined in that ?

Comment: You're rooting your '/' url to a HomeController. Run 'rails g controller home index' and then try again.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your issue is this line here:

```
root :to => "home#index"
```

In the routes.rb file.

This tells your application that the root URL (so the http://:3000/ URL) should look for a controller called 'home' with an action 'index'.

For this to work you would need to have a HomeController.rb in your app/controllers folder and inside that a def for 'index'.

I recommend running this command

```
rails generate controller home index
```

To generate the home controller. Many tutorials will give you this line to run BEFORE you run the scaffold command.

Comment: I did it now i got this message when i visit this 'home' button: Home#index
Find me in app/views/home/index.html.erb
Basically i want to show index page so that when clicked home button it shows all posts.

Comment: Good. This means that the page you are seeing is the default Home Controller page. You have two options here. Option 1: I suggest following the tutorial here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/getting_started.html. You have now done all the steps up to 6.2 Adding a Link. Section 6.2 will show you how to link to a page with all the posts.

Comment: Option 2: (Not recommended) If you want to take a shortcut, change your routes.rb file for the following: root :to => "posts#index" and the / URL will show you the posts controller

Comment: thanks @dsatch i did the same and it worked, no need to create home controller.

Answer (score 1):

`@PallavSharma`, let me give you some more information to help you:

> When you create `routes.rb`, you're basically telling Rails which
>   `domain.com/route` is going to "route" to which `controller#action`

The problem you have is that your stated controller (`home`) does not exist. And nor should it - it will be another controller with almost no significance in the rest of your app. If you want a custom `root` path, we generally just the `ApplicationController` like this:

```
#config/routes.rb
root to: "application#home"
```

This allows you to set the following:

```
#app/controllers/application_controller.rb
def home
    @posts = Post.index #-> whatever you want here
end

#app/views/application/home.html.erb
<!-- your code here -->
```

Although it might be logical, or even best practice, to use `posts#index` as the index; it means you'll have to use the posts `index view` for your home, as well as `posts/index`. By using `application#home`, it gives you a lot more flexibility, especially useful in large apps

Comment: No problem, hope it helps